# C# WPF MVVM ComboBox Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, combobox

First of all, what I'm trying to do is a "simple" binding of a `ComboBox` to my source.

The structure is something like:

```
public class Data
{
    public ObservableList<string> List {get;set;}
    public string Selected {get;set;}
}
```

Also, it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
My problem is, i found several solutions to do this via XAML, unfortunately i can't do it with XAML since my `ComboBoxes` have to be generated during runtime.

So my question is, how i can bind my `ComboBox` to `Data.List`, and also the selected item (value?) to Data.Selected, and this one should be `TwoWay` so my Data class knows that something was selected. Keep in mind this has to be through c# code (XAML is no option unfortunately).

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: And the combo boxes can't be generated by XAML (say an ItemsControl)?

Comment: Unfortunately not. :/

Comment: Actually the problem isn't the binding as Itemssource to List. The problem is the binding to Selected. E.g. (new ComboBox()).Itemssource = data.List;

Comment: Put both of these items as properties and use INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: sry forgot to mention, those are ^^ (edited post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy. Assuming, that `Data` has properties instead of fields:

```
public class Data
{
    public Data()
    {
        List = new ObservableCollection<string>
        {
            "Apple", "Orange", "Lime"
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> List { get; private set; }
    public string Selected { get; set; }
}
```

you can write this:

```
var comboBox = new ComboBox
{
    DataContext = new Data()
};

comboBox.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("List"));
comboBox.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, new Binding("Selected") 
{ 
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
});
```

To add `ComboBox` into visual tree, just call proper method for the container. E.g., this will work with any `ContentControl` (like `Window`):

```
AddChild(comboBox);
```

Answer (score 1):

> how i can bind my combobox to Data.List, and also the selected item (value?)

Create a custom *composite* user control which contains the combobox. Map the combobox's properties to two dependencies properties created on the custom control, one to load the data and the other to provide an on demand selected item's data. Any plumbing needs are done inside the codebehind which ultimately provides all the magic.

Then you can create/bind this control dynamically in codebehind as needed in the other page you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a sort of "recursive binding". If your combos are in a container control, what you need is bound the container to a collection of your single combo model, so each view in the ItemsControl will be bound to a single combo model.